# Is it possible to somehow cast Vec<Option<Value>> into Vec<Value> after filtering out None elements in Rust?

Tags: functional-programming, rust, iterator

I want some way to have such a cast when writing code like this:

```rust
struct Value;

fn remove_missed(uncertain_vector: Vec<Option<Value>>) -> Vec<Value> {
    uncertain_vector
        .into_iter()
        .filter(|element| match element {
            Some(val) => true,
            None => false,
        })
        .collect()
}
```

How can I achieve this? I believe that the type implication mechanism is not smart enough to determine that the resulting collection will contain only `Option<Value>` where all such objects are the same in terms of their type (`Value`).

The compiler answers my question partially:

```
error[E0277]: a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<Value>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `std::option::Option<Value>`
  --> src/lib.rs:10:10
   |
10 |         .collect()
   |          ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<Value>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=std::option::Option<Value>>`
   |
   = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<std::option::Option<Value>>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<Value>`
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`Iterator::flatten`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flatten) which creates "an iterator that flattens nested structure" – in this case, pulls out `Some` from `Option`.

```rust
let v = vec![None, None, Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(3)];
let filtered: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().flatten().collect();
```

Or [`Iterator::filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) to filter and map the element in one go – with an equal result.

```rust
let filtered: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().filter_map(|e| e).collect();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5cd6dc6a61776b512d546ed1b40e5bf1)

Comment: Thanks everyone for answers and pointing out a similar question! It is a great pleasure to be a part of such responsive and intelligent community!

Comment: I found that `flatten().collect()` does the trick and I'm pleasantly amazed. `Rust` is awesome!

Comment: yes. `flatten` is even nicer. I always forget that `Option` also implements `Iterator`